can we have localhost alias in chrome?
In Chrome, we can save common address and set keyboard shortcut ( what this thing actually called ?)  but when try to set alias of localhost
like if we type lh TAB 3000 then it open http://localhost:3000
but it does not accept this ; even tried with 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.1
any one know how can we set this? or do we have chrome extension for this


You are referring to "Site Search Shortcuts" in Chrome and you can read more about it here.
I can confirm that adding a %s after the colon (for the port) is not supported in Chrome. There seems to be some strange behavior with the colon. For example, if I type the shortcut lh and then type a colon it switches to searching my default search engine instead of using the shortcut.
With that limitation a workaround is going to be the only option.
Option 1: Site Shortcut for Every Port
This will be a pain if you have a lot of ports that you want to use. However, it is only a small handful you could set up a shortcut for each port. For example, you can set the shortcut to lh3000 and the URL would then be https://localhost:3000. Then repeat this for every port that you want to set up.
Option 2: Site Shortcut with Browser Extension

First setup a site search to localhost without the colon in the URL. I used the following settings:

name: localhost
shortcut: lh
URL: http://localhost%s


Install the redirector plugin (or one like it) and then use the following settings:

Description: localhost
Example URL: http://localhost:3000
Include pattern: http://localhost(\d+)(.*)
Redirect to: http://localhost:$1$2
Pattern type: Regular Expression

Then when you type lh (tab or space) in the address bar you can type 3000, enter and it will take you to http://localhost3000 and then the redirector extension will redirect you to http://localhost:3000. You can also specify a path if desired by typing 3000/some/path after the lh.

Thats seems patch
